# Does EOL == EOS in any other language besides BASIC?

Tags: vb.net, syntax, vb6, programming-languages, basic

BASIC and its variants Visual Basic and VB.NET are the only programming languages I know of that treat the end of line character as a statement terminator (I'm excluding batch files and command scripts from the domain of programming languages).  I'm curious: is there any other language that uses this convention, or does BASIC stand alone?

Comment: You mean EOL == EOS (end of *statement*)

Comment: I'd make this a community wiki if I were you; there's no "right" answer.

Comment: I assume you're treating VBScript as a variant of VB. :-)

Comment: @TJ - Seems to me there is a right answer. It's either yes or no.

Comment: @JohnFix: Heh heh heh. Does SO *allow* answers that are just two letters long? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [good breakdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28syntax%29#Statement_terminators) of languages and their statement terminators. According to that page, these languages are newline terminated:

- AutoHotkey
- GFA BASIC
- BASIC / Visual Basic / Visual Basic .NET
- Fortran
- Ruby
- Python
- AppleScript
- Windows PowerShell
- Boo
- MATLAB (result displayed)

Answer (score 4):

- FORTRAN - there's a continuation character if you need multiple lines
- All assembly languages that I'm aware of
- MS-DOS .BAT scripting language

Answer (score 2):

Several more not mentioned:

- Tcl. Although it supports semicolons as statement separators the standard/preferred convention is to write code without semicolons.
- Forth
- Haskell
- APL

**update**: Ah.. forgot. Almost all shell "languages" do this:

- sh/bash
- csh/tcsh
- ksh

Comment: You are wrong about FORTH - a newline is just a token separator.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript in most cases. Javascript has implied simicolons.

Most of the just for fun languages:
Brainfuck, LOLcode, whitespace (not sure on this one), etc.
Assembly does also as someone already pointed out.

Most modern languages do not treat EOL as an EOS.

Comment: _"Most modern languages"_ -- not true. Python, Ruby and Haskell are all modern languages that treats end of line as statement separator. In fact, I'd say there is a trend for newer programming languages to do this.

Comment: @Malfist: *"I said most, not all."* Okay. Such as?

Comment: Java, C, C++, C#, Erlang, PHP, perl, etc

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head:

- JavaScript's "automatic semicolon insertion" means it treats newlines as end-of-statement when certain rules apply.
- Ruby treats newlines as statement terminators, unless there's an operator in front of it in which case it continues the statement on the next line.